# iOS - SearchDisplayController - SearchBar style

Tags: ios

I'm working with SearchDisplayController and want to apply a style or tint to the searchBar. 
But I noticed that the SearchDisplayController makes changes to the style of my searchBar.

For example if I use the "Dark Text Color" tint on my searchBar, when running the app, I'll obtain a grey style. But if I remove the searchDisplayController linked to the searchBar, the style in the app is ok.

This image shows the difference between the searchBar in the storyboard and in the app.
[image: difference between searchBar in the storyboard and in app]

Note: If I use the default style, I don't have any problem.

I don't understand what changes the searchDisplayController adds to the searchBar.
Am I missing something or doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

No, you are not doing something wrong. While I'm not sure why it works this way, I can imagine that a somewhat lighter color is chosen in order to distinguish the cancel button (which will have your tint color).

What worked for me was to set the background color to black, no tint color (default), and use the Black Translucent style.

Also remember that when you set a tint color, the style is ignored.

I remember struggling with this for hours, just to get a black search bar.

Comment: Thanks now I can have a black search bar. But my goal was to put this search bar in my navigation bar that has a color gradient ... I can't find any way to obtain the same style with a SearchDisplay Controller

Comment: @adriencog: What style/tint color do you use on your search bar without the search display controller? I mean so that it looks good with the navigation bar.